# Will frozen chat rooms be deleted?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

My question is the title: Will frozen chat rooms be deleted? I am interested in particular in the case where nobody talks in the room for years.

In the chat faq there is [an item on retention](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention), which says the following.

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

This is slightly ambiguous to me. The text hints strongly at indefinite retention of rooms "worth retaining". However, the only real guarantee that appears to be made is "Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room".

Comment: Well, pretty sure that once a room is frozen, it will never be deleted. E.g. [this room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/606) is frozen for years.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you, that settles it I think. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, better wait for official response (i.e. from a dev) for a while, and if none is given, post this "best guess" as answer. :)

Comment: By the way, this is valid support question, can't see any reason to hide behind a fresh new account to ask it... I know MSE is scary and intimidating, but still... we don't bite *that* hard. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard w.r.t the fresh account; I don't want to have a reputation of being pedantic/impractical on this site. In addition some people who know my account name might say I should be working on my thesis. I suppose the fact that I can talk freely about my thesis on this account is also nice.

Comment: Fair enough. Have fun under that invisibility cloak! ;)

Answer (score 4):

It will never be deleted. The frozen state is block them. But not to remove them