# Is chat room transcript link permanent?

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

I just solved a problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406549/64403) after chat with OP.

Is it ok I share the transcript link in the updated answer ? I wonder the link may get expired or only accessible by [high reputation user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288612/make-chat-room-transcripts-forever-public-if-the-room-was-auto-deleted) after certain amount of inactivated days.

Comment: Transcripts are archived for years, I found [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1/2010/10/19) from 2010. The chat room may be closed, but the transcript will not be deleted. [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277010/will-frozen-chat-rooms-be-deleted) for another similar question on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transcript links are durable.  However, rooms with little activity are auto-deleted, meaning that only users with high rep (10k on that chat server) can see them.  According to the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention), a room is retained if it has more than 15 messages (combined) from at least 2 users.

If the room has enough messages to prevent deletion, then go ahead and edit a link into your post if that helps support your answer.  There's no rule against including chat links.

A comment mentions room links versus transcript links.  Rooms are frozen after a period of inactivity even if not deleted, so a room link doesn't allow people to talk in the room anyway but (in my opinion) presents a slightly more confusing interface to users unfamiliar with chat.  I recommend always using the transcript link.  Both links have the same level of visibility -- either the room is still around (but frozen) or it's been deleted and requires 10k rep to see either link.

Comment: Since https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69166/discussion-between--and-user145959 (room link) and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/69166 (transcript link) is different, so I wonder room and transcript deleted(hide for high reputation users) in the same time OR transcript may solely retained to public.

Comment: The transcripts are remained public. A quick google search can bring up a chat transcript, as well as the page being opened in cache content if needed. **Chat transcripts are never destroyed** you may not be able to access the room link but you can always access the transcript. For ease of access you could bookmark the page. Screenshottings also an option for peace of mind.

Comment: @JakeSymons Transcripts of deleted rooms are subject to the same 10K rep restriction as the room itself. An example from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300223): [deleted room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1055/log-of-meta-posts) and [its transcript](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1055) - both require 10K to access.

Comment: @6'whitemale **Chat transcripts are never destroyed** You may require 10K access but the transcript is not deleted or removed. For peace of mind, and for those with low rep levels the best option would be to screenshot the page. At the current time on Stack Exchange chat transcripts are never removed, however like all terms and conditions, this is subject to change. If it changes, I will update my comments.]

Comment: @JakeSymons I summarized the rules for auto-deletion.  If the room isn't subject to auto-deletion, the transcript will remain (unless the rules change).  It is always better to link or include actual text rather than a screen shot if you can, for accessibility.  (Font-size directives and screen readers can't do anything with a screen shot.)